# MySQL: Counting Latest Occurrences of Field in Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables that store information about the status of a project.

Not sure if this is possible in one query as we're currently using multiple queries to get this data.

We have tables for projects, status types and status history.

The status history table I'm working with consists mainly of project_id, status_id and date_added.

```
project_id    status_id    date_added
1             1            2013-06-10 13:19:20
2             1            2013-07-12 09:12:17
3             1            2013-08-26 22:44:42
1             2            2013-09-24 16:28:25
2             2            2013-10-25 12:52:48
```

I need to find out how many projects are currently at each stage. So I need to look at each project and get the status_id of it's latest record in the table.

So I need the returned data as the following.

```
status_id    count
1            1
2            2
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select status_id, count(1) cnt
from statushistory h
where not exists 
 (select 1 from statushistory h1 
  where h1.project_id=h.project_id and h1.date_added>h.date_added)
group by status_id
```

[Here it is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1343/2) to test in SQLfiddle

This is its version, checking projects table:

```
select status_id, count(1) cnt
from statushistory h, projects p
where p.project_id=h.project_id and p.active=1
 and not exists 
 (select 1 from statushistory h1 
  where h1.project_id=h.project_id and h1.date_added>h.date_added)
group by status_id
```

See it in fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf7ec/1)

Of course to run this effectively, you definitely need index on `(project_id,date_added)` and maybe on `status_id` too (see if its presence changes query executin plan).

I am not sure if low perfomace caused by subquery in where-clause is a myth or not, but here is a version without it (based partly on [Mosty Mostacho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268273/mosty-mostacho)'s code). You are welcome to compare these queries and tell us which is performing better.

```
select h.status_id, count(*) cnt FROM (
 select project_id, max(date_added) maxdate 
 from statushistory
 group by project_id
) h1, statushistory h, projects p
where h.project_id=h1.project_id and h.date_added=h1.maxdate
 and p.project_id=h.project_id and p.active=1
group by h.status_id
```

See it in fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf7ec/4)

Comment: Be wary of this for performance...MySQL and it's engine is very well known for handling subqueries written in this fashion very poorly (any other DB, this works well on).  If you start having larger volumes and you notice very poor performance, the culprit will be the subquery in the where clause.

Comment: If we wanted to go further and add a where clause that checked the projects table as well, how would go about that?

Comment: To answer something, I need to know more about the nature of projects table checking.

Comment: We simply have an `active` field and we need to check if the project is active or projects.active=1

Comment: Thanks Mas, we've tested and deployed the second query which was running significantly faster. Thanks again for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Is the assumption that the max status ID is the most recent?

```
select statusID, count(1) as recordcount
from
(select project_ID, max(status_id) as statusID
from statushistory
group by project_id)a
```

If that assumption is incorrect and you need to use the max(date_added) instead, then this logic can be slightly altered to look for max(date_added) and joined back to get the status of that most recent.  Let me know if you would like to see that code

Comment: Status id is most likely a dictionary code of a kind "1: project started, 2: project finished". That is why they want such a count.

Comment: Yes we use it in exactly that way. It's for use in a dashboard to give a idea as to how many items are currently at each status.

Comment: Ah yes, you would want to do the max(date_added) logic instead of max(statusID)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-correlated subquery solution:

```
SELECT h1.status_id, count(*) cnt FROM (
  SELECT project_id, max(date_added) date_added FROM history
  GROUP BY project_id
) h2
JOIN history h1 USING (project_id, date_added)
GROUP BY h1.status_id
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9add/1).

**Edit:**

I've just stumbled with this question again. In order to join more tables you just need to add them above the group by:

```
SELECT h1.status_id, count(*) cnt FROM (
  SELECT project_id, max(date_added) date_added FROM history
  GROUP BY project_id
) h2
JOIN history h1 USING (project_id, date_added)
JOIN projects p USING (project_id)
WHERE p.active = 1
GROUP BY h1.status_id
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a76ac4/1).